# Confirming an Alert Message in FireFox acts differently then in Chrome

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

My Selenium infrastructure is based on chromedriver version 2.46 and geckodriver version 0.24. My automation infrastructure is based on Python that runs over Windows 7 and Windows 10.

For some unknown reason not all the Alert Message confirmations (the accept button clicks), that I simulate in FireFox (Version 66.0.3), are "accepted" while I can say that in Chrome (Version 74) all the confirmations are actually accepted.

```
try:
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present())
    alertDialog = self.driver.switch_to_alert()
    alertDialog.accept()
except:
    print('Alert message didn\'t popup')
```

What, might be the problem ?

Is there a known issue in FireFox ?

Are there any other ways to do the accept ?

Comment: I will add and say that I do see the alert message pop-up and i do see it disappear after the accept action. But, the action that I expect to be done by the accept is not done

Comment: What happens when the action expected after the pop-up close is not done? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: It can finally lead to an error. This accept is part of a chain of actions that will lead to an expected status change of the object under test. And when the action has ended without actually changing the status then it will harm the whole chain.